# How to call a function from another model?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I am practising the yii1.1. I have two model that have a same function, how to merge them?

```
class Issue extends TrackStarActiveRecord
...
{
public function getUserText($user_id=null)
    {
        $sql="SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE id= $user_id";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $username = $command->queryAll();
        return $username;
    }
}


class Project extends TrackStarActiveRecord
{
...
public function getUserText($user_id=null)
    {
        $sql="SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE id= $user_id";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $username = $command->queryAll();
        return $username;
    }
}
```

I want to call the getUserText() function from two different views, but I don't want to write a same function in two different models. So I need to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to duplicate code and to fetch user name in classes those are not describing users.
You can put method in class User:

```
public $id;    
public function getUserText()
        {
            $sql="SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE id= $this->id";
            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
            $username = $command->queryAll();
            return $username;
        }
    }
```

and execute it:

```
$user = new User();
$user->id = 55;
$username = $user->getUserText(); // better call it getName()
```

Another way is to use ActiveRecord, see Yii documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

You can make a  static method in user model:

```php
class User extends CActiveRecord {

    public static function getUserText($id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE id= :id";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        return $command->queryAll(true, array(':id' => $id));
    }
}

// and call it
$username = User::getUserText(5);
```